# Yum does not seem to recognize the $releasever variable in the Centos repos file

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I was trying to use yum on a Centos 7 cluster to install a package, and I was getting the following error:

```
One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown), 
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only 
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this: [...]
```

I tried several suggested solutions online (`yum clean all`; deleting the cache; deleting the repo-databases and rebuilding, etc.) and nothing worked.

After hours of troubleshooting, I managed to find a workaround. On the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file, I uncommented the `baseurl` line and replaced the `$releasever` variable with "7" (i.e. the version of the OS). For some reason, yum could not recognize $releasever and could not find the repo.

So instead of:

```
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
```

I have:

```
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/$basearch/
```

after which both yum update and yum install seem to work fine. However, I don't know if this is a permanent solution to the issue.

Can someone tell me what's going on and if there's a more proper way to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What does this command return?


`rpm -q --qf "%{VERSION}\n" --whatprovides redhat-release`

Comment: @jsbillings It returns 7.

Comment: for me it returned "7.9" which is no good as $releasever should be "7Server" in my case!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem. Setting `releasever` worked for me. I also found that I could fix the `distroverpkg` setting in `/etc/yum.conf`.

I set it to:

```
distroverpkg=centos-release
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```bsh
yum --installroot=/usr/local install nginx --releasever=7
```

but why it is failed was still not figured out.